# How to save a spark RDD in gzip format through pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So I'm saving a spark RDD to a S3 bucket using following code. Is there a way to compress(in gz format) and save instead of saving it as a text file.

```
help_data.repartition(5).saveAsTextFile("s3://help-test/logs/help")
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization)

Comment: May I suggest you to use a [parquet](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#manually-specifying-options)? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`saveAsTextFile`  method takes an optional argument which specifies compression codec class:

```
help_data.repartition(5).saveAsTextFile(
    path="s3://help-test/logs/help",
    compressionCodecClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec"
)
```